# How to change Map coordinates format in React Native?

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-maps, react-native-firebase

In firestore database, I've location stored in this form - location: **[30.4345685454346° N, 2.134343291302° W]**

How can I remove ° N and ° W from the coordinates when I fetch them?

Also, the coordinates are set into the Firestore api using this way 
`location: new GeoPoint(position.latitude, position.longitude)`

Answer (score 0):

`GeoPoint` is basically firebase's object type to store latitude and longitude. I'm assuming you have `react-native-firebase` installed. Then you can retrieve latitude and longitude as follows

```
const yourGeoPoint = new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(someLatitude, someLongitude);

const latitude = yourGeoPoint.latitude; // this will give the latitude
const longitude = yourGeoPoint. longitude; // this will give the longitude
```

More documentation on this can be found at https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/firestore/reference/GeoPoint